# ImageMagick working on production, but not locally (Rails 4, Paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip, ubuntu-15.04

I've installed ImageMagick on my local (Ubuntu 15.04), and on my production server (DigitalOcean Dokku stack). I used the same process, but different directories.

On **production**, `which convert` and `which identify` results in `/usr/local/bin/convert (or identify)`, and on my **local** it results in `usr/bin`. All is good on my production server, but my local gives me the following error:

```
def raise_because_imagemagick_missing
      raise Errors::CommandNotFoundError.new("Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.")
end
```

**The server log will be at the bottom of this question.**

My `production.rb` doesn't specify any path for Paperclip commands or image_magick. I've tried doing the same on `development.rb`, but get the same error when trying to upload an image. I've also tried just specifying `:command_path` and just specifying `:image_magick_path` as well as both at the same time with variants of the following code in `development.rb`:

```
# Paperclip config:
  Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "/usr/bin/"
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
```

**Local WEBrick Log:**

```
Started PUT "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-05 14:03:39 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AjOr280FDoUbV7Qpt4rrLMlvuConAefSBc8F3rCCgRVmC91Anpb7qPeovrpvDhe9WxtNmWKSQdERcNUaoaPdqQ==", "user"=>{"username"=>"nickdb93", "email"=>"baughmann1@gmail.com", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f99f09f2f40 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150805-4838-1lomun.png>, @original_filename="qwesterasquare wall tile.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"qwesterasquare wall tile.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (58.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (50.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (52.1ms)  BEGIN
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/ba7aa9a469e508addbc1d5969021e8f220150805-4838-74vlew.png'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/360eb7a818c12ce00c2ac594df5aa9a020150805-4838-14hhllz.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
   (50.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 363ms (ActiveRecord: 211.4ms)

Paperclip::Errors::CommandNotFoundError (Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.):
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb:45:in `raise_because_imagemagick_missing'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb:30:in `rescue in geometry_string'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb:16:in `geometry_string'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb:9:in `make'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/geometry.rb:26:in `from_file'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb:34:in `initialize'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/processor.rb:33:in `new'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/processor.rb:33:in `make'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:524:in `block in post_process_style'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:523:in `each'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:523:in `inject'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:523:in `post_process_style'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:514:in `block in post_process_styles'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:513:in `each'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:513:in `post_process_styles'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:505:in `block (2 levels) in post_process'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_avatar_post_process_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/callbacks.rb:36:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:503:in `block in post_process'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_post_process_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/callbacks.rb:36:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:502:in `post_process'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:458:in `post_process_file'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:108:in `assign'
  paperclip (4.3.0) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:66:in `block in define_setter'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `each_pair'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `each_pair'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:250:in `block in update'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:249:in `update'
  devise (3.5.1) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:71:in `update_with_password'
  devise (3.5.1) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:94:in `update_resource'
  devise (3.5.1) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:48:in `update'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (7.1ms)
  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (23.7ms)
Cannot render console with content type multipart/form-dataAllowed content types: [#<Mime::Type:0x007f9a05d76418 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">, #<Mime::Type:0x007f9a05d76148 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:text, @string="text/plain">, #<Mime::Type:0x007f9a05d62148 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:url_encoded_form, @string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">]
```

I'm at a loss of what to do. I'm digging through the log output but I can't seem to find a good place to begin. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
--Nick.

Comment: Isn't `usr/bin` a relative path in your local environment? Meaning that the configuration path would be either `~/usr/bin`, or `./usr/bin`

Comment: @emcconville You're right, that does make sense. However, both of those seem to yield the same error :/